# SQL Oracle Trigger For Calculating and Updating Table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm  trying to create a trigger for the insert operation of the `TRAVELEXPENSE` table.

Here is my updated code

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_updates_requesttotal 
AFTER INSERT  ON TRAVELEXPENSE 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE REIMBURSEMENTREQUEST 
SET ReimbursementTotal = :NEW.ExpenseAmount
WHERE ReimbursementRequestID = :NEW.ReimbursementRequestID;
END;
```

Comment: You need to `JOIN` tables by `ON` condition, not `WHERE`. But after you successfully compile the trigger, you'll face `ORA-04091: table TRAVELEXPENSE is mutating`, because in a row-level trigger you cannot select from the same table. According to your code you do not need to access this table, just set new amount directly (or your subquery is invalid and returns multiple rows). Please, provide sample tables with sample data and describe what you want to achieve as a result of some consecutive transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors I can see:

```
WHERE TE.ReimbursementRequestID = RE.ReimbursementRequestID
```

should be

```
ON TE.ReimbursementRequestID = RE.ReimbursementRequestID
```

And

```
WHERE ReimbursementRequestID = NEW.ReimbursementRequestID
```

should be

```
WHERE ReimbursementRequestID = :NEW.ReimbursementRequestID
```